# Use sympy for calculation of nested sums invoking matrix entry

Tags: python, sum, sympy

I try to implement a nested summation. For readability, I use sympy. Now I found a dead-end. The code sequence calculate the matrix entries of `F_np`. Currently, for sake of simplicity, `f_np` remains zero. Later, the summed values are integrated. Therefore, the nested sums need to be explicity calculated and not remains as algebraic notation.
Sympy always keeps the algebraic notation when calling `doit()`.

For example `F_np[0,1].doit()` returns the following instead of 0.

[image]

As `l` can on run between 0 and 0 it has to remain 0. Since `m` has to be zero and also 0. So in this case, we call the sum of entry `[0,0]` which shall be zero as well.

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import Matrix, symbols,Sum,Min,Max

l=symbols('l',integer=True)
m=symbols('m',integer=True)
j=symbols('j',integer=True)

k_limit=2

p=2
n=2

f_np=Matrix(np.zeros([k_limit,k_limit]))
F_np=Matrix(np.zeros([k_limit,k_limit]))

for n in range(0,k_limit):
    for p in range(0,k_limit):
        F_np[n,p]=Sum(
                     Sum(
                        Sum(
                            f_np[m,p-j-1]
                            ,(j,l,Min(p-1-m,p-1))
                            )
                        ,(m,Max(0,n-l-1),p-1-l)
                        )
                    ,(l,0,p-1)
                    )
```